# WP API & ACF - Fetch options page

Tags: php, wordpress, api, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

Currently working on an react project together with the WP API & ACF using https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api. Everything worked well, but now i've to fetch the ACF Option Page. Can't see an available endpoint for this, just `/wp-json/acf/v3/options/{id}`?

Thanks for help guys

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update:** Solved the problem by setting the id to options `/wp-json/acf/v3/options/options`.